# How do I upload Windows contacts to Windows Live Contacts?

Tags: synchronization, contacts, google-contacts, office-365, outlook.com

I've just purchased a windows phone, however, all of my contacts are in the windows contacts store on my PC from when I had the iPhone (itunes would sync to that locally).

I would like to upload all of my windows contacts to the live contact store in the cloud (or even gmail contacts), but can't seem to find an easy way of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I just downloaded windows live mail, logged in with my live ID, and it synced everything up for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

There are two web services that might help you:

- [Soocial](http://www.soocial.com/)
- [Plaxo](http://www.plaxo.com/)